# I am really interested in doing phd, need help for title/topic, please help me

Tags: thesis

Me having master in communication engineering and degree in computer science, i am really interested in persuing phd to follow my father footstep.

I am interested in:

1) networking

2) image processing

4) Data mining and automization

5) Information technology

Or relevant

What i am good:

1) strong in math
2) strong in computer literature
3) fundamental of programming
4) strong in networking
5) strong in IT

Comment: Welcome to Academia SE, but that’s a question that you have to answer yourself or in consultation with a potential supervisor.

Comment: Any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is very unlikely for you to finish a PhD **if** you persue it to *follow your father's footsteps*.

And persuing a PhD is not buying a car. You cannot just list your interests and your budget, and wait someone to advise you a programme. You must already have a research topic in mind by the time you finish your MSc thesis. Or, you must be able to say that you will not pursue a PhD.

All that being said, I prefer you to pick computer networking.

Comment: Can you say why computer networking?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Since he is strong in math and networking. Plain and simple.

Comment: I didn't have a topic in mind for years into my program, though I didn't have a Master's degree when I started either. Your "musts" are too strong.

Comment: @BillBarth Might be too strong. but not having a master's degree ia an exception to what I've said.   I'm sure that if you had a master's, then you would have already decided on the topic.

Comment: @cagirici, I'm not. I watched a number of folks come through our lab starting with a Master's with almost no inkling of a decided topic. Many of those people just knew they wanted to something different than what they had just escaped!